# 64/32 bit integer issue in pycurl windows

Tags: python, windows, 32bit-64bit, libcurl, pycurl

I am trying to upload a large file (>2GB) using pycurl and encountered a strange issue. when uploading from a 64-bit nix machine (PycURL/7.19.3 libcurl/7.35.0) the file is uploaded without any problems, when running the same code from a 64-bit windows (PycURL/7.19.5.1 libcurl/7.37.0) machine the upload fails.

I followed some guides, made sure that fs type (NTFS) supports large files, made sure nginx on the server side is configured properly, but still no luck.

After further debugging, I saw that the underlying http request sent from the windows machine has a faulty size attribute:

```
Content-Length: -1320951182
```

the actual file size is: 2974015488.

if I check in the python cli on the windows machine I get:

```
>>> type(2974015488)
6: <type 'long'>
```

if I check in the python cli on the linux machine I get:

```
>>> type(2974015488)
2: <type 'int'>
```

I guess I need to somehow trick pycurl on the windows machine to accept the value as an int, I tried multiple variations using ctypes and fiddling with sys.maxint and sys.maxsize but none worked.

Is there a way to tell python to use 64 bit integers instead of longs?

Thanks

P.S - I need to use pycurl because all other options dump the file onto the RAM (yes, even requests in stream mode)

Comment: int and long were unified in python 3, did you try changing version?

Comment: upgraded to v3.4, now type(2974015488) returns int, but pycurl still gives: Content-Length: -1320951182

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing matters.

When using libcurl, you should pass the file size when larger than 2GB as a curl_off_t type to the [CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE.html) option. That type should be 64bit on all known 64bit architectures including win64.

If pycurl doesn't do that, it is wrong. If it *does* do that, the problem is something else...

Comment: python doesn't recognize CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE  or curl_off_t parameter

Comment: Then you know where to go next... =)